# xcode: how customize toolbar buttons for an iPhone app

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to replace the standard buttons in a toolbar. I'm creating an app for iPhone.
It's clear that Xcode allows you to choose images to customize the buttons, but when I try, all the buttons are show as just blue boxes (or circles in this case (because the imagens I created are circles with a transparent background.[Xcode screen with a toolbar and two buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3CrU.jpg)

I created a single button with the same image with no problem, but at the tool bar the opaque pixels appears as flat blue.

I'm using PNG images that I dragged to "Assets.xcassets" in three sizes: 29x29 pixels, 58x58 pixels and 87x87 pixels.

Comment: Are you using jpg or png images? Not sure if this would affect it but I know jpgs don't do transparency.

Comment: Any pixel that is not transparent in the image will be drawn as blue.

Comment: Try to use small size/dimension image, to reduce SO overhead. :)

Comment: I found a way to do it. You must create a tool bar and, separately, create individual buttons. Customize the buttons with the image you want and drag it to the tool bar. Worked for me.